# Accessing data from couchdb using angularJS as frontend and nodeJS as backend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, couchdb

I am new to web development. I want to develop a web application using angularJS, nodeJS, Express and couchdb. The registered user will be given some tasks. So the app must maintain data of tasks assigned to a user and tasks completed by the user. It should also maintain the data of users when they register for this app.
**I am able to access data(user name,tasks assigned to user,tasks completed by user) from couchdb through nodejs. But I don't know how to make angularjs access the data accessed by nodeJS and display it on web page. I would like to know how to access that data and display it on webpage.**You can take tasks as repairing a chair or something.

Comment: Ajax. You can use jquery or whatever you like to fetch data from server.

Comment: Thanks. But can't we access the data by using only angularJS, nodeJS and couchdb.

Comment: Of course. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http . You need `express` to process requests.

Comment: If possible can you show an example with a piece of code for accessing and using the data. (Using angularJS, node JS, Express and couchdb). Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, probably not now. To make it, you need to learn what ajax is. How does client send requests to server? How does server receive the requests , fetch data from database, and return it?